# Entity Framework 5 Connection Pooling In MultiThreading

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework

I am relatively new to Entity Framework and have limited knowledge on entity frameworks/sqlservers connection pooling functionality. I have to implement a multithreaded operation that includes database changes.

The MainMethod looks for new database entries and queues up the tasks using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem().

I am having database operations in the child threads too. For that I am creating the dbcontext object in the child thread.

I would like to know if the way I have implemented will have any performance issues. Will my child threads be creating new connection strings or reusing available ones. I have read that Entity framework makes use of the sql server pooling functionality but don't know how exactly.

```
public class DataProcessor
{  
    public void MainMethod(DataUow dataUow) //Entry point (Main thread)DataUow is the repository class
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var toDoMessageList = dataUow.MessageDumps.GetAll().ToList();  //Get Records
                if (toDoMessageList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var message in toDoMessageList)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunThread, message); 
                        message.ThreadHandlingStatus = 2; //Do changes to message 
                        dataUow.MessageDumps.Update(message); //and update           
                    }
                    dataUow.Commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
        }
    }

    private  void RunChildThread(object messageDataSent)
    {
        using (var dataContext = new DataUow(new RepositoryProvider(new RepositoryFactories())))
        {
            try
            {
                //Some Long Task Including Database changes
                dataContext.Commit(); //Repository method that contains the entity framework .SaveChanges()
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataUow is the repository pattern class.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code isn't very clear. But since EF don't support muti-threading, you should better create a new DbContext instance (DataUow) inside each new Thread you start, and call dataUow.Commit() inside each Thread too.

Comment: Thank you. I am told that creating a new database connection is resource intensive and that entity framework supports the database pooling of sql server. Will creating a new dbcontext instance create a new database connection each time? [Sql Server Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

Comment: Creating a new dbcontext instance is really light and fast. Connection pooling is handled internally by Ado.Net, (which is used by EF), if you reuse the same connection string. So you don't have to care about, if each dbcontext instance use the same connection String, the Ado.Net connection pool will be reused.

Comment: Should `RunChildThread` be `RunThread` (or reverse)?

Comment: To clarify, .NET connection pooling will create connections as they are needed up until the maximum number allowed.  As soon as you release the connection it will be re-added to the pool an re-used by the next query.  There will be one connection pool created per exact connection string used.  As others have said, you shouldn't have to worry about it, it will automatically create, open, and close connections for you.

Comment: @Sharped and Jtimperley Thank you, that clears it up for me. Gert Arnold, Yes it should be runthread. I had changed the function names while posting here. Been a bit careless while editing. My bad.